# The author didn't write $\mathcal{T}$ is the minimum topology on $X$ which contains all basis elements. ("Topology 2nd Edition" by James R. Munkres)

Tags: general-topology, soft-question

I am reading "Topology 2nd Edition" by James R. Munkres.

> **Definition.** If $X$ is a set, a ***basis*** for a topology on $X$ is a collection $\mathcal{B}$ of subsets $X$ (called ***basis elements***) such that
> (1) For each $x\in X$, there is at least one basis element $B$ containing $x$.
> (2) If $x$ belongs to the intersection of two basis elements $B_1$ and $B_2$, then there is a basis element $B_3$ containing $x$ such that $B_3\subset B_1\cap B_2$.
>
> If $\mathcal{B}$ satisfies these two conditions, then we define the ***topology $\mathcal{T}$ generated by*** $\mathcal{B}$ as follows: A subset $U$ of $X$ is said to be open in $X$ (that is, to be an element of $\mathcal{T}$) if for each $x\in U$, there is a basis element $B\in\mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in B$ and $B\subset U$. Note that each basis element is itself an element of $\mathcal{T}$.

If $\mathcal{T'}$ is a topology on $X$ such that $\mathcal{B}\subset\mathcal{T'}$, then $\mathcal{T}\subset\mathcal{T'}$.
So, $\mathcal{T}$ is the minimum topology on $X$ which contains all basis elements.
I think this fact is important, but the author didn't write that.
I wonder why the author didn't write that.
Any reason?
Is it unimportant to note this fact?
Because the author didn't write this fact, I thought $\mathcal{T}$ is a Topology but what $\mathcal{T}$ is.
I thought if $\mathcal{T}$ is special or not.

Comment: It is contained in the word 'generated'. You wouldn't say that the power set of $\mathbb R$ (the discrete topology)  is generated  by the class of open intervals or that $\mathbb R^{2}$ is generated (as  a vector space ) by  a single vector.

Comment: Kavi Rama Murthy, Thank you very much for your nice explanation.

Comment: The author didn't write that, but you figured it out for yourself? Maybe he didn't write it because he *expected* you to figure it out for yourself.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if this was an exercise at the back of the chapter. But I don't have my copy available, so I can't check.

Comment: @bof Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @Arthur Exercise 5 on p.83: Show that if $\mathcal{A}$ is a basis for a topology on $X$, then the topology generated by $\mathcal{A}$ equals the intersection of all topologies on $X$ that contain $\mathcal{A}$. Prove the same if $\mathcal{A}$ is a subbasis. Thank you very much for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a clue why the author didn't write it. It's just not the place to write it, because we can express it in more general manner: involving the notion of *subbases*. As you pointed out, the family of sets is a basis of some topology only if it satisfies two conditions. What if the family doesn't satisfy it? It isn't a basis of any topology (the formula you mentioned doesn't provide us with a topology), but we can consider the smallest (not only minimal!) topology containing all the sets from our family. This is a place for our new character: a subbasis.

If $\mathcal U$ is any family of subsets of $X$ then the family $\mathcal B$ of all intersections of finite subfamilies from $\mathcal U$ forms a basis (satisfies before mentioned two conditions) so it generates a topology.

Precisely, for any $\mathcal U\subset 2^X$ the family
$$\mathcal B = \mathscr B(\mathcal U) := \left\{
\bigcap U_0 \,|\,\mathcal U_0\subset U,\ \#\mathcal U_0<\infty \right\}\hspace{1cm}(*)$$ is a basis and the topology $\mathcal T$ generated by it is the smallest topology containing $\mathcal U$, i.e.
$$\mathcal T = \bigcap\{\tau\,|\, \tau\text{ is a topology on }X\text{ and }\mathcal U\subset \tau\}.$$ Then $\mathcal U$ is called a subbasis of $\mathcal T$.

In particular, if $\mathcal U$ is a basis, and $\mathcal B = \mathscr B(\mathcal U)$ is the basis generated by it (by the formula (*)) then both bases $\mathcal U$ and $\mathcal B$ generate the same topology, which implies that the topology generated by this basis is the smallest among all topologies possesing all sets from our basis.

Comment: If $\mathcal U$ is a basis, then it is not always true that the basis $\mathcal B(\mathcal U)$ generated by  $\mathcal U$ via $(*)$ agrees with $\mathcal U$. We only have  $\mathcal U \subset \mathcal B(\mathcal U)$. This comes from condition $(2)$

Comment: @PaulFrost ok, I meant that it generates the same topology. I'll make a correction. Thank you for pointing this out.